# The field 'custom_39' has no associated option list

Tags: custom-fields, groups

This error comes up when I try to edit or create a group:

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. The field
>   'custom_39' has no associated option list.

It produces a 732K long error log that I will not paste here. Any hints how I would debug this one.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have a smart group that relies on a custom field which you have since disabled or deleted. See if you can find the id of the smart group in that huge backtrace. Or else try re-enabling that field to see if the problem resolves itself.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I found out in a different way. I did not find custom_39 in the civicrm database, but I could in the drupal database cache tables.

Comment: @ñull How did you take care of it in the cache tables?

Comment: I used the cache tables to analyse the issue, not to solve the issue. How I took care of it is in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the issue was related to the extension **Auto Group Assignments (org.amnesty.es.autogroupassignments)**. I had this deinstalled, but apparently does not do so correctly. Both disabling and deinstalling gives DB already exist errors. I can now only edit/create groups with this extension activated.

The work around is to do a manual but partial clean-up after deinstall:

- drop table ***civicrm_value_automatic_group_assignments*** (and *possibly **log_civicrm_value_automatic_group_assignments***)
- delete ***Affects_API_calls*** and ***Default_Group_for_New_Contacts*** from *civicrm_custom_field*
- delete ***Automatic_Group_Assignments*** from ***civicrm_custom_group***

This however still leaves you with a *DB exist* error when you reinstall the extension